# Getting DIV from ajax using a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I am trying to get a specific div to load using ajax by passing it a variable through the data property but I think I have something wrong with the syntax. I couldn't get it to work using .load() either.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('a.load-project').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var toLoad = $(this).data('project');
                toLoad = '#'+toLoad;
                loadProject(toLoad);                                    
            });

function loadProject(projectDiv) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'projects.html',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {'id':projectDiv},
                success: function(data){
                    $('.project-load-area').html(data).slideDown();
                }
            });
        }
```

EDIT: I got this to work this way:

```
 $('.project-load-area').load('projects.html #'+toLoad ).slideDown();
```

Getting some help with the longform version of AJAX would be very helpful though.

Comment: Is your request returning expected data?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent using $.ajax would be:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'projects.html',
     dataType: 'html',
     data: {
         'id': projectDiv
     },
     success: function (data) {
         $('.project-load-area').html($(data).find('#projectDiv').html()).slideDown();
     }
 });
```